# In Nand2Tetris course, what are the virtual machine commands that access the screen or keyboard memory maps?

Tags: cpu-architecture, low-level, nand2tetris

How does the virtual machine language in nand2tetris access screen or keyboard memory map?

There does not seem to be any segment which directly accessses the screen among these virtual memory segments: this, that, local, arg, temp.

For eg. How are these functions implemnted in the VM language?

- Memory.peek(720)
- Memory.poke(120, 74)
- do Output.printString("Ting ting);
- 

etc

I looked into the VM code from the compiled Jack code but could not understand which memory segments in VM language correspond to the keyboard and screen memory maps.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://www.nand2tetris.org/project09), there are 2 versions of these APIs supplied - one as .vm files and the other as .java files.

> The Nand2tetris Software Suite includes two Jack OS implementations. One OS implementation was written in Jack, and was then translated using a Jack compiler into the set of 8 class files Math.vm, Screen.vm, Output.vm, Keyboard.vm, Memory.vm, String.vm, Array.vm, and Sys.vm. These files are stored in the nand2tetris/tools/os folder in your computer.

For example, the file `nand2tetris/tools/OS/Memory.vm` contains all the memory functions, so you can check out how exactly these things would work in the VM. Here are the first 3 memory functions from that file:

```
function Memory.init 0
push constant 0
pop static 0
push constant 2048
push static 0
add
push constant 14334
pop temp 0
pop pointer 1
push temp 0
pop that 0
push constant 2049
push static 0
add
push constant 2050
pop temp 0
pop pointer 1
push temp 0
pop that 0
push constant 0
return

function Memory.peek 0
push argument 0
push static 0
add
pop pointer 1
push that 0
return

function Memory.poke 0
push argument 0
push static 0
add
push argument 1
pop temp 0
pop pointer 1
push temp 0
pop that 0
push constant 0
return
```